# How to efficently truncate a many-to-many table in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA many to many relation.

The easiest way of deleting all entries of this relation is doing a `findAll()`, clearing the collection of the assoziation and flushing the session.

In my case this means loading ~1'000'000 instances into ram just to delete them all. That's not really efficient.

I could resort to SQL and simply truncate the join table. Is there an efficient way to do this in JPA?

Comment: No, there is not. SQL is the right tool to do that.

Comment: you can write an hql query sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("delete from MyEntity").executeUpdate();

Comment: That fails, because the integrity constraint on the m:m table is violated.

Comment: Agreed with JB. JPA is a great tool for approaching data in a more application-friendly way, but it does not make SQL obsolete - far from it. SQL is a perfect tool to do what needs to be done here. Consider doing it in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to map your m-m table as an additional entity and delete it with a [delete statement](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/delete#Selective_Deletion_). If the table is not mapped to an entity, it cannot be deleted by a delete statement. If you just want to delete the m-m relations, this should be enough. If you also wnat to delete related entities, you should map them to the new m-m entity and mark the relationship with cascade on delete.

Comment: Although this is still slow compared to a SQL `TRUNCATE` statement, I think that's the best one can get with pure JPA.